# How to have an auto calculated attribute in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

suppose I have following mongoose schema in Node.js

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    views:Number,
    clicks:Number,
    ctr:Number
})
```

In which I want that CTR attribute should be automatically calculated by a formula based on values of other attributes, i.e lets say

> **ctr = clicks / views**

I don't want to have CTR as a virtual field because based on the value of CTR I will sort all documents of my collection and apparently sorting is not possible based on virtual fields. So I was wondering if there is any way to have calculated attributes in mongoose schema which gets automatically updated on update of any of the dependent attribute/field

Comment: you can do it using mongodb aggregation. In aggregation you can have calculated fields based on your choice. In `$project` stage you can calculate your fields and can use in successive stages

Comment: to @nurulnabi I want these calculated values to be actually available in DB. Will that  do?

Comment: do you want `ctr` to be calculated before the document gets inserted.

Comment: @nurulnabi yes, I want 'ctr' to be calculated while document gets inserted and ALSO WHEN any of the dependent values get updates. I knew prior part could be done using save hooks but I couldn't find any way to update 'ctr' value based on current value of update of view & clicks values.

Comment: for that you need to use mongoose middleware. In case of new document insert `schema.pre('save',fn)` you can do your calculation easily but in case of update(update middleware `schema.pre('update',fn)`) you need to fetch the record and do the update then recalculate fields then update that.

Comment: I had thought about the similar approach but then I was reluctant for it because during pre('update') hook I have to anyway fetch the document explicitly and then do my calculations. That's why I was expecting any natively supported better way since such requirements would not be so rare, I guess. Anway thank you for your comments

Answer (score 18):

> I want that CTR attribute should be automatically calculated by a
>   formula based on values of other attributes

From the [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html) [emphasis added]:

> **You can also set the default schema option to a function.** Mongoose
>   will execute that function and use the return value as the default.

Therefore, your example could be rewritten as:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  views: {
    type: Number
  },
  clicks: {
    type: Number
  },
  ctr: {
    type: Number,
    default: function() {
      return this.clicks / this.views
    }
  }
})
```

> So I was wondering if there is any way to have calculated attributes
>   in mongoose schema which gets automatically updated on update of any
>   of the dependent attribute/field

If I understand correctly, note the section in the docs on the `setDefaultsOnInsert` option. This may be of relevance when recalculating the default upon update.

Answer (score 10):

You can use for it virtual field:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    views:Number,
    clicks:Number
})

schema.virtual('ctr')
  .get(function() {
    return this.clicks / this.views;
  });
```

Comment: thanks @Sergaros for taking time and answering my question but as I have mentioned in question I don't want to have CTR as a virtual field because based on the value of CTR I will sort all documents of my collection and apparently sorting is not possible based on virtual fields. So I was wondering if there is any way to have calculated attributes in mongoose schema which gets automatically updated on update of any of the dependent attribute/field

Answer (score 7):

You can do anything, but don't forget about that that difficult thing slower your server.

In my case for calculating age user I do that.

```
const mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    const userSchema = new Schema( {

      born: {
        type: String,
        get: a => {
          let date = new Date(a);
          let today = new Date();
          let timeDiff = today.getTime() - date.getTime();
          let age = Math.floor( timeDiff / ( 1000 * 3600 * 24 ) / 365 );
          return age;
        },
        set: age => age,
        alias: 'age',
      },
    } 

);

module.exports = mongoose.model( 'User', userSchema );
```

And [Mongoose Documantation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use the **Pre-save middleware**. I am implementing that in my Schema and it works good so far. The caveat is that it will be not triggered for updates, though. The format is the following:

```
schema
  .pre('save', function(next){
   this.ctr = this.clicks/this.views
   next();   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also another way, taken from the highest rated answer from this post [Mongoose pre hooks for save and update do not get called when i used a Model.findOneAndUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992758/mongoose-pre-hooks-for-save-and-update-do-not-get-called-when-i-used-a-model-fin) is:

```
yourSchema.post("findOneAndUpdate", async function() {
  const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());
  // do your calculations
  // await docToUpdate.ctr = docToUpdate.clicks/docToUpdate.views
  await docToUpdate.save();
});
```