# Mongoose pre hooks for save and update do not get called when i used a Model.findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have created a an express application with mongoose. I also created a save and update hook as follows :

```
userSchema.pre("update", async function save(next) {
    console.log("inside update")
     });

userSchema.pre("update", async function save(next) {
    console.log("inside save")
     });
```

but anytime I call a `Model.findOneAndUpdate()` the pre hooks are not called, does the `save` and `update` prehook not work for `findOneAndUpdate` ?

Comment: Hi, did you check my answer?

Comment: @SuleymanSah yes sir, it was perfect

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated in mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) Pre and post save() hooks are not executed on update() and findOneAndUpdate().

You need to use `findOneAndUpdate` hook for this. But you cannot access document which will be updated using this keyword.  If you need to access the document that will be updated, you need to execute an explicit query for the document.

```js
userSchema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", async function() {
  console.log("I am working");
  const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());
  console.log(docToUpdate); // The document that `findOneAndUpdate()` will modify
});
```

Or if you can set a field value using `this.set()` like this:

```js
userSchema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", async function() {
  console.log("I am working");
  this.set({ updatedAt: new Date() });
});
```

Let's say we have this user schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

userSchema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", async function() {
  console.log("I am working");
  this.set({ updatedAt: new Date() });
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

And this user document:

```
{
    "updatedAt": "2020-01-30T19:48:46.207Z",
    "_id": "5e33332ba7c5ee3b98ec6efb",
    "name": "User 1",
    "__v": 0
}
```

When we update this user's name like this:

```js
router.put("/users/:id", async (req, res) => {
  let result = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    { name: req.body.name },
    { new: true }
  );

  res.send(result);
});
```

The `updatedAt` field value will be set to the user, and it will be updated.

Comment: The first method worked after I called docToUpdate.save(). But the second way with this.set({ }) updates the doc, console logs the correct value, but does not save changes in db.

Answer (score 1):

you can use save() function with findOne():

```
const newName = 'whatever';
const user = await User.findOne({id});
user.name = newName;
user.save();
```

This will call pre hook but you need to watch for the paths you are changing in pre save function